# How can I change the Javahelp font?

Tags: java, fonts, javahelp

Javahelp is the Java based help system that can easily be integrated in a Java application. The documentation does not give any information about it. On the web, many people state that it is not possible, that the help browser always uses a built-in font. I am not convinced that it is not possible.

The help system of the IntelliJ IDE is based on javahelp and uses another font. So I think it must be possible. Is there someone who actually did this?

For completeness:

- Including  tags in the help
  files does not help.
- Stylesheets do
  not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stylesheets seem to work ... in certain circumstances. Probably only a subset is supported, and the trick is to find out which one.

Comment: The class doc for `javax.swing.text.html.CSS` lists the CSS subset that is supported by HTMLEditorKit.